# Method in controller stops at httpClient.SendAsync(request); ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, model-view-controller

I am trying to call a method in the controller from a webpage. However, when the code runs it stops executing at httpClient.SendAsync(request);. Never goes beyond that.
It works fine in a .net console app but not in a ASP.NET web application.

This is my method:

```
public static async Task<Employee> LoadData(int ID)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://api.example.net/api/GetData"))
        {

            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Basic TOKEN HERE");
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
            JToken t = o.SelectToken("$.value[?(@.Id == " + "'" + ID + "'" + ")]");
            string a = t.ToString();
            Employee e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(a);



            return e;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the controller method:

```
public JsonResult Test()
{
    try
    {
        Api.LoadData(507);

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see the action name is `Test` while you are trying to send a request to this Url: `https://api.example.net/api/GetData` which is `GetData` Not `Test`

Comment: Your LoadData(int ID) method is async, hence your Test() method should be async as well

Comment: You need to `await` the call to `Api.LoadData(507);` as right now, you return before the method is completed.

Comment: Thanks guys, really helped

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

Using [`Task.GetAwaiter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter) to wait `LoadData` is completed then return value.(**Warning**: It's calling an asynchronous `LoadData` and blocking on it synchronously so it's not asynchronous  at all and it can cause to deadlocks as well.)

```
public JsonResult Test()
{
    try
    {
        Api.LoadData(507).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Or you can change `Test()` method as `async`:

```
public async JsonResult Test()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, please mark answer as an accepted by clicking the check-mark, so that it helps the others.